# Get user Access Token from Twitter in Angular 2+ app

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter, angular6, twitter-oauth

Hi I want to get a twitter user access token/refresh token so that My application can post/read tweets on behalf of the user..

I have a button in my app.. on clicking of the button, I need to show something like below image - [image]

user should be able to provide his/her credential and if it is already logged in to twitter then he/she should only see authorize app button..

I created a new app in my developer twitter account.. but little clueless on how to get user's access token to post/read behalf of him...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Twitter uses OAuth1.0a unlike Facebook which uses OAuth2.0. The difference between OAuth1.0a and OAuth2.0 is that OAuth1.0a is more secure and you should use a server-based authentication flow because it involves api keys and secrets which we shouldn't be sharing with angular app.

On server side (NodeJS/Django, etc) you should use a client library for OAuth1.0 which will help you in complicated process of signing requests befores sending it to twitter. 
Here is a useful link (which I also used) for you to implement the server flow: 
https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/master/docs/oauth1_workflow.rst

Basically, the OAuth flow for twitter is as follows:

1. Send a POST request to `oauth / request_token`
2. You will get the authroization url from Step 1 like this `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXX` which you will redirect the user to so that they can authorize your app
3. Twitter redirects the user to your redirect url (which you sent with the request in previous step) with `access_token` and `verifier`.
4. You need to exchange the `access_token` and `verifier` for the actual usable user access token by sending a `POST` to `oauth/access_token`.

You can find more details for 3-legged OAuth flow here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth

Comment: Do you know of any examples...maybe a tutorial?

Comment: @TomMcDonald check this link https://github.com/ideoforms/python-twitter-examples/blob/master/twitter-post-status.py